Lags, artefacts and LOW fps in game if i open youtube or anything in full screen in another monitor
Lags, artifacts and LOW fps in game if I open youtube or anything in full screen in another monitor. Two monitors full HD 1 60HZ and Primary 75. I tried changing the refresh rate, but it made no difference.

Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic x86_64
bits: 64
compiler: N/A
Desktop: KDE Plasma 6.0.4
Distro: KDE neon 22.04 6.0
base: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy
Graphics: Device-1: AMD vendor: Sapphire driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.0 isplay: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.4 compositor: kwin_wayland driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080 OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6650 XT (navi23 LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-28-generic) v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes


there is a bug report describing what you have.
A possibly relevant merge request was started,
they said it's fixed by that commit.
the next update should fix that problem
